# Use custom hook inside a callback in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I have this custom hook:

```js
const useSomething = () => {
    const displayAlert = (text) => {
        alert(text);
    };
    return {displayAlert};
};
```

Now I want to use it somewhere in my code like following:

```js
const SampleComponent = () => {
    const {displayAlert} = useSomething();

    const navigateHandler = (event, page) => {
        // some api
        // ...
        displayAlert('Some alert');
    };

    const navigateHandlerCallback = useCallback(() => {
        navigateHandler(null, 1);
    }, []);

    useEffect(navigateHandlerCallback, []);

    return (
        <button onClick={e => { navigateHandler(e, 5); }}>
            Navigate to 5th page
        </button>
    )
};
```

**Now the problem is eslint warning that says:**

> React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'navigateHandler'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

**And when I include *`navigateHandler`* as a dependency into `useCallback` dependency array, eslint says:**

> e 'navigateHandler' function makes the dependencies of useCallback Hook (at line XXX) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the 'navigateHandler' definition into its own useCallback() Hook

- I cant change `navigateHandler` function.
- I'm not sure if another callback can solve my problem with best performance or not.

#### What should I do about this?

Comment: Wrap the navigate handler in a useCallback like it says. Also, your custom hook is not a hook, since it is not using React hooks. It's just a function.

Comment: @JMadelaine the custom hook is just a sample in here, but in my code is a custom hook that uses some react hooks. The thing is I need the navigateHandler not just for using inside the useEffect, As you can see, I use it in `onclick` of my button.

Comment: 1. Create a wrapper for navigateHandler and define it inside useCallback to get rid of the warning. 2. For performance optimizations you need to measure the performance before useCallback and after it, and last but not least, you need to have a performance problem before you start optimizing for performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your custom hooks with `useCallback`:

```
const useSomething = () => {
    const displayAlert = useCallback((text) => {
        alert(text);
    };, [])
    return {displayAlert};
};
```

Then within your component:

```
const SampleComponent = () => {
    const {displayAlert} = useSomething();

    const navigateHandler = useCallback((event, page) => {
        // some api
        // ...
        displayAlert('Some alert');
    }, [displayAlert]);

    const navigateHandlerCallback = useCallback(() => {
        navigateHandler(null, 1);
    }, [navigateHandler]);

    useEffect(navigateHandlerCallback, []);

    return (
        <button onClick={e => { navigateHandler(e, 5); }}>
            Navigate to 5th page
        </button>
    )
};
```

By using `useCallback` this will surely improve performance during renders.

Comment: I didn't know about the arguments that `useCallback` can pass to my function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `useCallback` will pass the same args with which  you invoke the method

Comment:  The `useEffect` now loops !

Comment: Don't add deps in `useEffect` only add for `useCallback`

Comment: Add empty list add deps []

Comment: I did, but eslint says: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'navigateHandlerCallback'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

Comment: As `useEffect` should be executed only on mount you can safely disable warning using `// eslint-disable-line` or `// eslint-disable-next-line`